# One word for a letter without sender's address

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What is a letter without a sender's address called?

Comment: If it's only about the sender's address, you can describe such a letter with *unbouncable* or *unreturnable*, but this is an adjective about such a letter, not a word meaning a kind of a letter. Also related is [dead letter mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_mail), but it's about undeliverable, not just about the absence of the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **anonymous letter**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymity

"anonymous" means that a person's name is not given.

These letters are called "anonymous letters" because the sender didn't write his/her address/other identification on the letter, so the sender's identity is unknown, and thus the sender is anonymous.

Comment: I think that this is what the OP wants, but this also implies that the letter itself is unsigned, not just the address on the envelope.

Comment: I think if a letter has the sender's name without his address, the letter cannot be called an anonymous letter.

Comment: That's why we need extra info about that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a single word for a letter without sender's address.

You usually say *a letter with no return address* or *a letter without the sender's address*.